# Arduino のプログラム中のSerial TXを移植するには

Tags: spresense, シリアル通信

Arduino のプログラムをSpresense＋LTE開発ボードに移植しようとしています。

以下のドキュメントを参考にして、拡張ボードのUART端子でsoftwearSerialは5V機能しています。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_uart%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95

この状態で、メインボードのD00,D01でArduinoの標準のSerial関数でTxピン（ArduinoUnoの１番ピン）をつかって、9600bbsでTX信号を出力したいのですが、ハードウェア的に使えないのでしょうか？

Serial2としてプログラムして、コンパイルや書き込みはできるのですが、動作していない様子です。
なにか、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メインボード側の端子だと1.8V I/Oなので、電圧が合ってないということはないでしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございます。レベルコンバータを接続し、ヘッダファイル内でSerialで指定されていた箇所をSerial2で置き換えることでメインボードのD00で通信ができました。